# How to complete a service task using camunda rest api

Tags: camunda

I am using Camunda workflows to automate various processes. I have come across a scenario where the process is not moving from a service task. Usually, we call the `task/{taskid}/complete` to complete the task, but since the process is stuck on a service task, I am not able to complete that task. Can anybody help me find a way to complete the service task?

[image]

Comment: As you are using service task, can you check in your Service implementation whether there is any error or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a service task. That basically means "a machine should do something". The "normal" implementation is to provide code (a java Delegate or a connector endpoint) that is called by the process engine to execute this task.

The alternativ is to use the "external task" pattern. Think of external tasks as "user tasks for computers". So the process waits, tells subscribed clients that a job is to be done and waits for their completion.

I suppose your process uses the second option? (you can check in the modeler under "Implementation"). So completion can be done through the external task API, see [docs](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/rest/external-task/post-complete/).

`/external-task/{id}/complete`

Comment: we are using "Connector Endpoint" to implement the service task. Does that mean, I don't have any means of completing that task?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a connector then you likely will see when checking the log that retries have occurred and that the transaction rolled back. After addressing the underlying issue the service task (email) should be sent without explicitly triggering the service task and the following user task (Approval) should be created.